# Remote neo4j gremlin inconsistent results

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, gremlin-server

I setup a neo4j server, gremlin server and gremlin console. I am connecting gremlin server to neo4j with SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt. When I add several nodes and try to fetch all nodes afterwards from gremlin console, I get inconsistent results. It doesn't return all nodes.

neo4j.properties

```
gremlin.graph=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.Neo4JGraph
#neo4j.graph.name=graph.db
neo4j.identifier=dummy
neo4j.url=bolt://localhost:7687
neo4j.username=neo4j
neo4j.password=pass
neo4j.readonly=false
neo4j.vertexIdProvider=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.providers.Neo4JNativeElementIdProvider
neo4j.edgeIdProvider=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.providers.Neo4JNativeElementIdProvider
```

That is how i add nodes and their results

```
gremlin> g.addV('cat').property("name","sylvester")
==>v[null]
gremlin> g.addV('cat').property("name","tom")
==>v[null]
gremlin> g.addV('cat').property("name","garfield")
==>v[null]
gremlin> g.addV('mice').property("name","jerry")
==>v[null]
```

Neo4j Browser shows these nodes without a problem. But when i query from gremlin-console i get different result as follows

```
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>{name=[garfield]} 
==>{name=[sylvester]} 
==>{name=[tom]} 
==>{name=[jerry]} 

gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>{name=[garfield]}
```

Comment: with what command do you connect to Gremlin Console to Gremlin Server?

Comment: :rem connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml

Comment: given your method of connecting from console to server, i can't think of why you would end up in this situation. what happens if you explicitly rollback on every request? in other words try: `gremlin> g.tx().rollback();g.V().valueMap()`

Comment: Rolling back doesn't change the problem. Added nodes still appear sometimes in gremlin and always can be seen from neo4j browser ui.
But your previous comment made me thinking it might be about sessions. Then i try to manage session on my own with
`:rem connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session`
Then committing explicitly solve my problem as it looks like. 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above apparently lead to the answer here, but I can't say that I'm clear on exactly why the fix mentioned actually resolves the problem.

For those who come across this question, I will summarize how this sort of connectivity is expected to work. Connecting from Gremlin Console to Gremlin Server with:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

opens a sessionless connection which should create a situation where the server manages transactions for you, meaning each time you submit a request to the server, the a transaction is opened, the traversal executed and the transaction closed. It also means that any mutations to the graph should be automatically be committed (or rolledback on failure) at the end of each request. With that model, there should be no situation where you get stale or inconsistent data.

To build on that notion, performing a submission as:

```
gremlin> g.tx().rollback();g.V().valueMap()
```

under this (and any) connection model should automatically yield a fresh transaction explicitly and thus never produce a stale result set.

The following method of connection yields a session such that the user manages the transaction:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
```

and therefore may yield an inconsistent state. You must explicitly commit and rollback transactions as needed as the transaction can extend over multiple requests. In other words expect that it will be necessary to call `g.tx().rollback()` prior to getting the latest changes made to the graph in a different thread of execution.

The final connection option is as follows and it blends the two concepts:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session-managed
```

You get a session in the sense that variables are preserved between requests, but each request represents a single transaction which is commit or rolledback at the end of each request. Like a sessionless connection, you should not expect an inconsistent state or stale data and, as mentioned earlier, use of `g.tx().rollback()` prior to the query should force start a new transaction even if the managed transaction somehow failed to behave as expected.

If these things are not working as described here, I would likely wonder about the graph provider itself and whether or not its transaction semantics are completely compliant with the TinkerPop model.